# Optimized arithmetic methods in R

Tags: r

The openssl package implements a `bignum` class with the corresponding methods for arithmetic and comparison to perform calculations on arbitrary sized integers.

In cryptography there is a common special case for the [modular exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) `x^p %% m` which is used by e.g. rsa. For large `p`, calculating `x^p` is not feasible, but `x^p %% m` can be calculated efficiently which OpenSSL implements in [`BN_mod_exp()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BN_mod_exp.html).

Does R provide any mechanism to implement the  `^.bignum` and `%%.bignum` methods such that when evaluating `x^y %% z` we can call this special case rather than actually calculating `x^p`?

Comment: The question is if there is a way to export `^` and `%%` methods such that `x^y %% z` can use e.g. `powm(x,y,z)` rather than `mod(pow(x,y),z)`.

Comment: Look at `?Ops`. They are generic so if those operators are not defined by the call you desire, it should not be difficult to add a class-specific S3 or S4 method.

Comment: I think probably not exactly as you request.  Writing methods for individual binary operators (as @42- suggests) is no big deal, and @TheTime proposes a reasonable alternative, but I don't think the parser/user control of the parser is flexible enough to recognize that `x OP1 y OP2 z` ought to be interpreted as `F(x,y,z)` ...

Comment: I didn't think so either, but I did think that if `x OP1 y` returned an object of the same class as needed to be dispatched by `OP2.class` that you might get the action needed.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but *yes*, this is absolutely possible, and it’s a moderately common programming technique in some languages, such as C++, where the technique is known as [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).

R, being weakly typed, cannot quite harness the pattern to the same extent. But a “light” version is still possible.

In a nutshell, you define your `^.bignum` operator so that, instead or computing the result immediately, it returns a proxy object that signifies “exponentiation operation”. This proxy object has a specially overridden `%%` method that invokes the ExpMod implementation (e.g. `BM_mod_exp`). It also defines a method that coerces it to a `bignum` by evaluating the actual `x ^ y` operation.

In code this may look as follows:

```
# Vectorisation left as an exercise for the reader.

`^.bignum` = function (x, y)
    structure(c(x, y), class = 'bignum_mod_exp_proxy')

eval_exp = function (x)
    call_actual_exp(x[1], x[2])

as.bignum = function (x)
    if (inherits(x, 'bignum_mod_exp_proxy'))
        eval_exp(x)
    else
        # … implement other coercions to bignum, e.g. from `numeric`.

`%%.bignum_mod_exp_proxy` = function (x, y)
    call_BN_mod_exp(x[1], x[2], y)

# Pretend that a `bignum_mod_exp_proxy` in all other contexts. E.g.:

print.bignum_mod_exp_proxy = function (x, ...)
    print(eval_exp(x))

# … etc., for the rest of the `bignum` operations.
```

In fact, you could even override `=.bignum_mod_exp_proxy`, `<-.bignum_mod_exp_proxy` and `assign.bignum_mod_exp_proxy` (converting `assign` into an S3 generic), so that assignments `z = x ^ y` are eagerly evaluated to a `bignum`. However, this is probably overkill and would incur an overhead for each assignment.